# Go: print URI in template files (echo framework)

Tags: templates, go

I'm using `echo` framework. I'm stuck when trying to print URI `:mynumber` as variable in template files.

All variable working fine except the URI `:mynumber`. I have no idea how to include `:mynumber` together with `Name` & `Age`

Below is my `server.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

type Person struct {
    Name, Age, Mynumber string
}

type (
    Template struct {
        templates *template.Template
    }
)

func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}) error {
    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    p := Person{Name: "Mike San", Age: "35"}

    t := &Template{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseFiles("public/views/testhere.html")),
    }
    e.Renderer(t)

    e.Get("/testing/:mynumber", func(c *echo.Context) {
        c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", p)
    })

    e.Run(":4444")
}
```

Below is `public/views/testhere.html`:

```
{{define "onlytestingtpl"}}My name is {{.Name}}. I'm {{.Age}} years old. My number is {{.Mynumber}}.{{end}}
```

For your reference, below is example is print URI without template file:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Get("/users/:id", func(c *echo.Context) {
        id := c.Param("id")
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "My number is "+id)
    })

    e.Run(":4444")
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working though? I notice you pass the `p` variable to the `Render` method, which is an instance of a `Person` __without__ a `Mynumber` value set (only `Age` and `Name`). Perhaps that's your problem? We need more details as to the actual error occurring.

Comment: The `Name` & `Age` is working, but the problem is `:mynumber`

Comment: I have no idea how to include `:mynumber` together with `Name` & `Age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to retrieve it from the URL as per your working sample:

```
number := c.Param("mynumber")
```

And set it on the `Person` instance you're passing in:

```
p.Mynumber = number
```

Which would result in:

```
e.Get("/testing/:mynumber", func(c *echo.Context) {
    number := c.Param("mynumber")
    p.Mynumber = number
    c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", p)
})
```